# Collapsing a div and opening another one bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm trying to use the Collapse.
I want the div `#film` to hide when I click the `<li class="rekruterring>`and I'm missing something. It won't close no matter what I do, I've tried with accordion, `data-parents`, `javascript` and nothing makes the `#film`div hide when I click the `.rekruterring` and the `#rekruttering` div is shown.

Here's my code and be aware that the `#rekruterring` is expanding as it should, but is not hiding `#film`.

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */

/* DOES NOTHING */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rekruttering").click(function() {
    $("#film").collapse('hide');
  });
})
```

```css
/* VIMEO */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.video {
  background: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 100%;
  /* Thumbnails 5 across */
  margin: 1%;
}
.video img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.video img:hover,
.video img:active,
.video img:focus {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.categories li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="accordion" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h2 class="section-heading">Galleri</h2>
      <hr class="bg-primary">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 categories text-center">
      <ul>
        <a class="film" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#film" data-parent="#accordion">Firmapræsentation</a> |
        <a class="rekruterring" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rekruterring" data-parent="#accordion">Rekruterringsfilm</a> |
        <li>TV -/Biografspots & Imagefilm</li>|
        <li>Salgs- & Produktfilm</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="film" class="row text-centered collapse in">
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-centered">
      <article class="video">
        <figure>
          <a class="" href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>
            <img class="videoThumb" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/paG__3FBLzI/mqdefault.jpg">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <h3 class="videoTitle" style="text-align:center;">FILM</h3>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 text-centered">
      <article class="video">
        <figure>
          <a class="" href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>
            <img class="videoThumb" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/paG__3FBLzI/mqdefault.jpg">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <h3 class="videoTitle" style="text-align:center;">FILM</h3>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 text-centered">
      <article class="video">
        <figure>
          <a class="" href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>
            <img class="videoThumb" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/paG__3FBLzI/mqdefault.jpg">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <h3 class="videoTitle" style="text-align:center;">FILM</h3>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 text-centered">
      <article class="video">
        <figure>
          <a class="" href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>
            <img class="videoThumb" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/paG__3FBLzI/mqdefault.jpg">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <h2 class="videoTitle" style="text-align:center;">FILM</h2>
      </article>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- FILM -->


  <div id="rekruterring" class="row text-centered collapse">
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-centered">
      <article class="video">
        <figure>
          <a class="" href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>
            <img class="videoThumb" src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Cute-Red-Bunny.jpg">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <h3 class="videoTitle" style="text-align:center;">REKRUTERRING</h3>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 text-centered">
      <article class="video">
        <figure>
          <a class="" href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>
            <img class="videoThumb" src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Cute-Red-Bunny.jpg">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <h3 class="videoTitle" style="text-align:center;">REKRUTERRING</h3>
      </article>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-3 text-centered">
      <article class="video">
        <figure>
          <a class="" href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>
            <img class="videoThumb" src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Cute-Red-Bunny.jpg">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <h3 class="videoTitle" style="text-align:center;">REKRUTERRING</h3>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 text-centered">
      <article class="video">
        <figure>
          <a class="" href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>
            <img class="videoThumb" src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Cute-Red-Bunny.jpg">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <h2 class="videoTitle" style="text-align:center;">REKRUTERRING</h2>
      </article>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- REKRUTERRING -->

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you create third part link? Stackoverflow provides option for your code to be executed here in a page

***https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/***

Comment: Did not know that was a feature. I've added it to my question. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because there is a Bootstrap bug/issue when using the `parent` class. It relies on the use of the `panel` class being wrapped around your `collapse` elements.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19936/)

```
<div class="panel">
    <div id="film" class="row text-centered collapse in">

<div class="panel">
    <div id="rekruterring" class="row text-centered collapse">
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved the last hair on my head :-)

Comment: @ThomasThomsen Not a problem, glad to help out!